# Limit size of Subversion repository

Tags: svn

Hi I'd like to limit the size of my repository by specifying a maximum size, however I cannot find any information on doing so. Is this technically possible?

edit: sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to keep a functional repository where I can keep committing patches, however the oldest revisions of documents that have at least one newer revision can be automatically removed to stay within the sizelimit. so say that I can go about 67 revisions back because older ones have been removed (ideally keeping the commit messages).

Comment: Have you tried looking up "quotas"?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the size limit is exceeded? The repository becomes read-only for the rest of forever?

Comment: Interesting. I'd suggest you look into a commit hook on the server, of some variety. You'll have to do a bit of manual work on it though (i.e. calculate the size yourself, and reject the commit).

Comment: I don't think SVN is built for that, it doesn't really support manipulation of old revisions. You could probably do something like this with `git`, which lets you do a lot more history-editing than other VCS.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Disk space is almost free nowadays!

Comment: I don't think it's worth the enormous effort you would have to put into this, unless you are talking about limited storage capacities on a Space Shuttle or something. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doing this is major surgery on your repository. Make sure you're fully aware of what you're doing before doing this for real on a real repository.

You won't be able to do what you're after for individual files, but you can do this across the whole repository. What you need to do is cut off the history tail for the repository.

What this means is that if you've got 5000 revisions in your repository, and you cut off the oldest 1000 revisions, you'll end up with a repository with just the most recent 4000 revisions.

Doing this requires a dump/restore cycle, which means that you'll have to disable write access to the repository whilst you're working on and rebuilding the repository.

You won't lose any files that are still visible when browsing the repository, but the history for any particular file may be lost entirely (if all modifications to it were in the first 1000 revisions). Obviously if a file was deleted in one of the early revisions, you won't be able to get it back at all after the cut.

Also note that the naive way of doing this will renumber all of your revisions starting from 0, so in the above example, revision 5000 will become revision 4000 after the truncation. If this will cause you problems, you'll have to do extra work.

So, assuming we want to lose the earlist 1000 revisions, the basic workflow is:

1. Take your repository offline (or at least make it read-only)
2. run `svnadmin dump [repository path] -r 1000:HEAD > repository.dump`. This will create a dumpfile which only includes revisions from 1000 onwards. By **not** using the `--incremental` flag, the first revision in the dumpfile will contain a complete dump of the repository as it looked at revision 1000 (excluding all history).
3. Create a clean repository with `svnadmin create` and copy the conf & hooks directories from the old repository.
4. run `svnadmin load [new repository path] < repository.dump` to load up the most recent revisions.
5. Move the old repository out of the way (keep it around for backup) and move the new repository into its place.

If you want to preserve the revision numbers you'll have to load the empty revisions from somewhere. You can do that by dumping out the revisions 1:999 into a separate dump file and then using svn dumpfilter to get rid of everything from it, then load up the empty revisions followed by the revisions you want. It's a bit fiddly, but will get you there.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing effort in that answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way to do this. You will really need to *rebuild* the repository dropping the oldest revisions. There is no single SVN command for doing this. The process you need is roughly:

1. Do an **svnadmin dump** (which can be done only on the host).
2. Use **svndumpfilter** to filter out the unwanted revisions.
3. Create a new repository and use **svnadmin load** to load into the new repository.

This [link](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svndumpfilter) will give you some information on svndumpfilter, which is the crucial part of this entire operation.

Rethink: svndumpfilter gives control over which files/paths to include or exclude, but I'm not so sure it gives the fine grained control over revisions...

Answer (score 1):

In a pre-commit hook, you could "abort" the transaction if the repository exceeds a limit.

Comment: Id like to process all new transactions but have older revisions removed without losing any current versions of files.

Comment: @Pacifika: you'll need a daemon/cron job to perform this sort of operation on the server side. You could "gate/trigger" this process through the "commit hooks" though.

Answer (score 1):

Since all revisions in SVN are based on diffs of what came before, there is no way to "clean out" old revisions.  If you really need to do this for some reason, you will have to every so often take an export and re-import that into a new repository.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it.
on opposite to CVS, subevrsion doesn't keep the entire sources per revisions
but only a difference between upcoming revisions (well a little bit smarter but not important for this question)

Comment: I don't think CVS maintains entire sources either (only diffs).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create windows user account for SVN
2. Enable quota control for all NTFS drives (My Computer -> Drive -> Properties -> ...)
3. Setup quota limit to size you need (for ex, 20 Mb)
4. Configure SVN server to run under account you just created
5. Enjoy!