# Limit SVN repository size or files size

Tags: svn

How to limit `SVN` repository size without using `pre-commit hooks`?
 pre-commit hook raised when all files that needs to be commited are already on server.

My repository is public and I dont want to get over `500 Gb` files to be commited.

I want to limit repository to `5 Mb` size including all commits. May be I can use some 3rd party software to do this? For example software to limit folders size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit size of Subversion repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020490/limit-size-of-subversion-repository)

Comment: No, it is not duplicate: if some "good" guy will commit over XXX Gb file, 
1) It will be loaded into server
2) Cleaning history will do nothing for this case

Comment: Yeah, I see. Hmm, this may be impossible to do... How are you using svn? Maybe this helps? https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/visualsvn/odPaqr7D0SU

Comment: It will, but partially. User will be able to commit over 1 million of 5 Mb files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer:

1. Create windows user account for SVN
2. Enable quota control for all NTFS drives (My Computer -> Drive -> Properties -> ...)
3. Setup quota limit to size you need (for ex, 20 Mb)
4. Configure SVN server to run under account you just created
5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server you might be able to do (I've never had cause to do it myself so Its not granteed to work)

LimitRequestBody 524288000

in your directory configuration to limit commits,
To limit the overall repository size I'd suggest you use quotas...
I imagine it'll die rather ambiguously through once you hit the quota mind.
Out of curiousity what do you have against pre-commits?

Comment: Pre-commits happend after uploading files into server. Not before. Server can be attacked by uploading from 100+ bots of 100 Gb files. This will down my server.

Comment: true, then I'd suggest using precommits for the limiting the actual repo size along with the above server limitation to block far too large requests, along with something like modbw to limit the number of connections from a ip address?