# Subversion Commit Big file issue

Tags: svn, centos

I am trying to commit 15mb file in svn. But after 5mb transfer getting error message & commit failed.

Error message is

"svn: Server sent unexpected return value (413 Request Entity Too Large) in response to PUT request for ...."

I tried to use svn commit ,svn import.But no luck.

Any idea regarding same?

Comment: Is it your SVN server or some external service? It has maximum file size limitation. If it's yours - configure it properly. If it's not - there is nothing you can do, unless you negotiate with administration of that SVN service.

Comment: i followed steps give in http://www.krizna.com/centos/install-svn-server-on-centos-6/
to install svn on my centos server. Where exactly can i check for maximum file size limitation?

Comment: What SVN client do you use?

Comment: 15mb or 15gb? 15mb is not so big, in fact.

Comment: As bahrep says, is it 15mb or 15gb? If it's 15gb, your file system may limit file sizes to 4gb. Also, what is this file that it's so big? If this is some sort of built object, you shouldn't be storing it in Subversion. Instead, store it in some sort of _release repository_. Built objects take up a ton of room and have a really short shelf life. There's no advantage of storing them in a repository and all sorts of disadvantages. Is this source or a built object?

Comment: I am using tortoise svn

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this issue before.
The Apache server side error is:

```
Error: XML request body is larger than the configured limit of 1000000
```

The LimitXMLRequestBody default (when directive not present in http.conf) is 1000000 which is 1MB

To increase to 50MB add this line to httpd.conf (I put mine in my svn vhost section).

```
LimitXMLRequestBody 52428800
```

NOTE: LimitRequestBody vs LimitXMLRequestBody.  A prior answer mentions LimitRequestBody, this is not the correct option.

Comment: I installed svn on other vps & it worked absolutely fine.Not able to understand issue with the new VPS.Is it something to do with apache settings?

Answer (score 1):

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722768/limit-svn-repository-size-or-files-size), this might be Apache limitation. Search for `LimitRequestBody` setting in your Apache configuration (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) and set it to whatever you want.

Comment: LimitRequestBody is not present in http.conf.

Comment: I have added LimitRequestBody=0  at end of file http.conf file & restarted the httpd service & its still not working

Comment: Why 0? You should make it larger, then default, not cutting it off completely. And refer to http://objectmix.com/apache/665852-limitrequestbody-setting-maximize-upload-file-size-please-help.html for all the caveats you may encounter confuguring this.

Comment: <Directory "path of my svn folder having trunk folder">
    LimitRequestBody 524288000
</Directory> Is this code correct?I have added it at end of httpd.conf.

Comment: I set it to 0 bcas many site says default 0 setting will set maximum limit.