# Teamcity - build solution with missing dll in subverion

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to configure teamcity to do a CI build from our subversion repository. One of the dll required to build the solution doesn't exists in our subversion repository as it was too big to be uploaded to subversion. So of course the CI build currently fails as it cant find the Dll.

How does teamcity build work? does it download all the files from SVN to a local directory on the build server and does the build? I was wondering if I can manually copy the large missing dll to the build directory (if there is one)
or are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thanks

Suneeth

Comment: I'd suggest fixing the problem at source rather than working around it, which is always going to be an ugly solution. I don't think it subversion which is limiting your file size, but more likely the server configuration. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315349/subversion-commit-big-file-issue)

Comment: [This](https://subversion.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4&dsMessageId=337459) seems to suggest that subversion can handle files at least as large as 1 gb. I'd be amazed if your dll is that big.

Comment: What language is your source code?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Its c#

Comment: I'm assuming this is a 3rd party dll, otherwise you could potentially build it from source. Is this available as a .nuget package?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd . thanks.  the dll's are telerik sitefinity cms dll's. not sure they are available as nuget package